# C++ Best data structure to store last X incoming items?

Tags: c++, vector, stack

I was originally storing "incoming items" using a vector, but even with a large amount of RAM this was not practical. I therefore decided to store the last X received items.

What would be the best data structure to use? I was thinking of a std::queue? This is the pseudo code I was thinking of:

```
if(queue.size() == max_size){
    queue.pop()
}

queue.push(new_item);
```

The usage for the data structure would be to store a history of events and if used, would be to rollback- therefore iterating through each item in the structure.

Comment: I thought a deque is if you want to add/remove items on both sides? I only want to add items to one end and remove from the other end?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: `std::queue` use by default `std::deque`...

Comment: Boost has a circular buffer.

Comment: Not sure what you are really doing but normally you want to rollback things in the reverse order they were done.  If this is the case you are probably looking at a stack rather than a queue.

Comment: sound like you want a stack? a std::stack is a std::deque however

Comment: @Duck yes but I only want to store the last N items. A stack wouldn't allow that

Answer (score 8):

I'd use a [ring buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer) data structure. The C++ STL doesn't provide one but it is trivial to make. All you need is a fixed size array and an index.

Here is an example implementation, similar to the one I use:

```
#include <iostream>
template <typename T, size_t TSize>
struct RingBuffer{
    enum{array_size = TSize+1};
    T array[array_size];
    size_t read;
    size_t write;
    RingBuffer():read(0),write(0){}

    T& pop(){
        T* p = NULL; //Return NULL reference if empty intentionally
        if(read!=write){
            p=array+read;
            read = (read+1)%array_size;
        }
        return *p;
    }
    bool is_empty(){return write==read;}
    bool is_full(){return (write+1)%array_size == read;}
    void push(T& v){
        array[write]=v;
        write = (write+1)%array_size;
        //Gracefully handle write overflow
        if(write==read)read=(read+1)%array_size;

    }
};
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    RingBuffer<int, 10> r;
    for(int i=0;i<15;++i) r.push(i);
    while (!r.is_empty()) std::cout<<r.pop()<<"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, with a std::vector and an index pointer. This is more efficient than a queue/deque IMHO.

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt because of the continuous memory?

Comment: @user997112 Because you do not need to move memory around when you push or pop an item.

Comment: Yes, if you you have to iterate through it regularly. I was thinking more about memory allocation/deallocation, which is done only once with a vector/array as opposed to deques...

Comment: its a shame there is no standard ring buffer container

Answer (score 0):

Try deque, IMO it's what you are searching for:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/deque/deque/

Comment: Just so I know- if I am only adding at one and and removing from the other end why would I want a deque, rather than a queue?

Comment: @user997112 In most implementations the deque and queue class use an  identical data structure by default.

In fact, here is its declaration:

`template <class T, class Container = deque<T> > class queue;`

Answer (score 0):

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/circular_buffer.html

That might be what you are looking for?